# Custom XmlSerializer issue with null elements in a List<>

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a class that I want a custom serializer for. And I will sometimes use this class within a List, that I also want to serialize. Some of those elements will be null.

I can get serialization working:

```
<MyData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Fractions>
    <Frac>1/2</Frac>
    <Frac xsi:nil="true" />
    <Frac xsi:nil="true" />
    <Frac>3/6</Frac>
  </Fractions>
</MyData>
```

But de-serialization is not working when null elements are present like above. The List<> serializer appears to be invoking ReadXml() for a  element vs. just creating a null element in the list.

When I run my example, the de-serialized version is:

```
1/2
/
/
3/6
```

I.e. a MyFrac object was created instead of null in element 1 and 2.

Do I have to create a custom serializer for a List sub-class to get around this, or am I missing some other way to get null elements on de-serialize? If custom serializer, any best approach/code?

I have a complete example below which shows my current implementation.

```
public class MyFrac : IXmlSerializable
{
    public string N;
    public string D;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return N + "/" + D;
    }

    System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.IsEmptyElement && reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            reader.Read();
            return;
        }

        reader.ReadStartElement();

        string sfrac = reader.ReadString();
        try
        {
            var m = Regex.Match(sfrac, @"(\d+)/(\d+)");
            if (!m.Success)
                throw new Exception(sfrac + " was not in the correct format");
            N = m.Result("$1");
            D = m.Result("$2");
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.ReadEndElement();
        }
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteString(N + "/" + D);
    }
}

public class MyData
{
    [XmlArrayItem("Frac")]
    public List<MyFrac> Fractions;
}

public static void Run()
{
    var data = new MyData();
    data.Fractions = new List<MyFrac>();
    data.Fractions.Add(new MyFrac { N = "1", D = "2" });
    data.Fractions.Add(null);
    data.Fractions.Add(null);
    data.Fractions.Add(new MyFrac { N = "3", D = "6" });

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
    }

    // Dump XML
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

    using (var reader = new StringReader(sb.ToString()))
    {
        var data2 = (MyData)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        Console.WriteLine(data2.Fractions[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(data2.Fractions[1]);
        Console.WriteLine(data2.Fractions[2]);
        Console.WriteLine(data2.Fractions[3]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem occurs because of during deserialization XmlSerializer first create an object by calling default constructor and then call **ReadXml** method to set property values so **ReadXml** can't cancel object creation. Is it necessary to serialize null values to see it in xml? I mean that you may avoid this by using non-List collection. For example create your custom collection:

```
public class MyCollection : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<MyFrac>
{
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, MyFrac item)
    {
        if(item == null) return;
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }       

    protected override void SetItem(int index, MyFrac item)
    {
        if(item == null) 
        {
            base.RemoveAt(index);
        }
        else
        {
            base.SetItem(index, item);
        }
    }
}
```

Use it in your **MyData** class:

```
public class MyData
{
    [XmlArrayItem("Frac")]
    public MyCollection Fractions;
}
```

And then serialization/deserialization works as you want:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new MyData();
        data.Fractions = new MyCollection();
        data.Fractions.Add(new MyFrac { N = "1", D = "2" });
        data.Fractions.Add(null);
        data.Fractions.Add(null);
        data.Fractions.Add(new MyFrac { N = "3", D = "6" });

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
        }

        // Dump XML
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

        using (var reader = new StringReader(sb.ToString()))
        {
            var data2 = (MyData)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            foreach (var element in data2.Fractions) {
                Console.WriteLine(element);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Serialized xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Fractions>
    <Frac>1/2</Frac>
    <Frac>3/6</Frac>
  </Fractions>
</MyData>
```

Outputs:

**1/2**

**3/6**

**Update**

Ok, you need a colletion with custom serialization rules. Let's implement it:

```
public class MyCollection<T> : Collection<T>, IXmlSerializable where T: class 
{
    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        var wasEmpty = reader.IsEmptyElement;
        reader.Read();
        if (wasEmpty)
            return;
        while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
            {
                reader.Read();
                Items.Add(null);
                continue;
            }
            var item = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            Items.Add(item);
        }
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));
        foreach (var myFrac in Items)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, myFrac);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class MyData
{
    public MyCollection<MyFrac> Fractions;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new MyData();
        data.Fractions = new MyCollection<MyFrac>();
        data.Fractions.Add(new MyFrac { N = "1", D = "2" });
        data.Fractions.Add(null);
        data.Fractions.Add(null);
        data.Fractions.Add(new MyFrac { N = "3", D = "6" });

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
        }

        // Dump XML
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        Trace.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

        using (var reader = new StringReader(sb.ToString()))
        {
            var data2 = (MyData)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            foreach (var fraction in data2.Fractions)
            {
                var output = fraction == null ? "null" : fraction.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(output);
                Trace.WriteLine(output);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Fractions>
    <MyFrac>1/2</MyFrac>
    <MyFrac xsi:nil="true" />
    <MyFrac xsi:nil="true" />
    <MyFrac>3/6</MyFrac>
  </Fractions>
</MyData>
```

Output data:

**1/2**

**null**

**null**

**3/6**

I think this is what you want.

Comment: Null list elements have meaning. So I need these in the XML and restored.

Comment: Yes Deffiss, thanks. I had hopped that I overlooked some other XmlSerializer attribute I could apply to get the standard List serializer to "do the right thing", as this would seem to be a very common roadblock. Thanks again.